# How can I use GRUB instead of windows bootloader on more than 2 OS?

Tags: grub2, boot-loader

By default, my laptop has windows 10 installed. One day for some reason, I have to install windows 7. After the installation done, as expected, windows 7 bootloader appeared on boot.

On another day, once again for another reason, I have to install Linux on my laptop. After the installation done, GRUB bootloader appeared on boot, with the following items in the list:

1. Linux Mint Cinnamon blablabla
2. Advanced options for linux mint blablablah
3. Windows 7 (loader)

I didnt expect this one, why does the one appeared in the list is the loader instead of the OS? I dont like this. I want something like this:

1. Linux Mint blahblah
2. Windows 10
3. Windows 7

How can I accomplish this?

EDIT: My Partitioning:
[image]

- sda2 contains Windows 10 installation
- sda3 contains Windows 7 installation

Comment: Have you considered running one single main operating system, and then using a virtual machine for other OSes on top of that? VirtualBox runs Linux with little or no problem on top of Windows, for example.

Comment: Ikr!? But sadly my instructor told me to install it directly, without VirtualBox

Comment: The instructor told you to set up three OSes on a laptop? What class is this? On what technical ground would running the OS in VirtualBox not be allowed?

Comment: Lets forgot the instructor lol

Comment: Show your partitioning. Microsoft will sometimes use a boot loader that the BIOS jumps to then loads Windows (FAT32; think UEFI). Sometimes the Windows OS is alone without the boot loader. More info on your setup will help get your question answered.

Comment: @jc__ I've updated my answer.